# access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked

Tags: magento2, rest-api

```
access to XMLHttpRequest 'api link' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has 
been blocked by cors policy: response to perflight doesn't pass access to 
contrsol check: it doesn't have http ok status
```

I've built magento apis and my partner call those apis through ionic and get that error
I have added following lines to .htaccess file in magento root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
<FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
</FilesMatch>
```

and added those lines to httpd.conf in apache:

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
</Directory>
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests
Please confirm if it helps.

Comment: @MilindSingh it didn't work

Comment: @MilindSingh I did some thing wrong while installation, so it didn't work, but now it's working thanks.

Comment: I have faced same issue.You find any solution @YomnaMansour .

Comment: @LovelySetia This extension https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests is the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood.

It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers: Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the Origin header.

A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser when needed. In normal cases, front-end developers don't need to craft such requests themselves.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

**Magento 2 Api does not support pre-flight request by default**. You can modify the apache or nginx server config for handling the request.
For example http://snippi.com/s/or2myzn

I would suggest installing the following module for handling the CORS pre-flight request in Magento 2 Api:

https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests

Answer (score 1):

You are running into CORS issues.

There are several ways to fix/workaround this.

```
Turn off CORS. For example: how to turn off cors in chrome
Use a plugin for your browser
Use a proxy such as nginx. example of how to set up
```

More verbosely, you are trying to access api.serverurl.com from localhost. This is the exact definition of cross domain request.

By either turning it off just to get your work done (OK, put poor security for you if you visit other sites and just kicks the can down the road) you can use a proxy which makes your browser think all requests come from local host when really you have local server that then calls the remote server.

so api.serverurl.com might become localhost:8000/api and your local nginx or other proxy will send to the correct destination.