# Magento 2 NO Access-Control-Allow-Origin redirect on other web site

Tags: magento2, cors

In my Controller I use

```
$this->_response->setRedirect($url);
```

I got this error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' (redirected from 'myWebStoreUrl')
>   from origin 'myServerUrl' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

What should I do?

Comment: please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252236/access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked it might help you

Comment: I tried but have the same error, in magento 1 i have no problems to go to this site..

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
  $redirect->setRedirect($url);                                                                         I tried like this, same error...